# PHP and MySQL using named parameters, is this right?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using $_POST to pass variables into a script. Those variables are then used to shape the sql query. I'm trying to use named parameters but, while it works, I'm not sure how the colon parts work or are supposed to work in my example. I think I understand the bindValue() part, I'm just not understanding how it integrates/connects into the SQL. I feel like my query is incomplete even though it seems to be working properly. Any explanation or guidance is appreciated.

```
$answerNumber = $_POST['answerNumber'];
$questionNumber = $_POST['questionNumber'];
$answerText = $_POST['answerText'];

try {
    //INSERT QUERY
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $questionNumber ($answerNumber) VALUES ('$answerText')";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':questionNumber', '%' . $questionNumber . '%');
    $stmt->bindValue(':answerNumber', '%' . $answerNumber . '%');
    $stmt->bindValue(':answerText', '%' . $answerText . '%');
    $stmt->execute();

    $errorInfo = $db->errorInfo();

    if(isset($errorInfo[2])){
        $error = $errorInfo[2];
        echo $error;
    } else {
        echo "No errors.";
    };

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Edit: The example I'm looking at to help me uses a SELECT not INSERT and uses a "WHERE make LIKE :make" statement that mine doesn't have. Not sure what is happening here. Thanks!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

No, you're doing it wrong. You're not using any parameters in your actual query string, and are directly inserting outside data into the string, leaving you wide open for [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

The proper format is:

```
INSERT ... VALUES(:param1, :param2, ....., :paramN);
```

for the query string, and then

```
$stmt->bindValue(':param1', $value_for_param1);
$stmt->bindValue(':param2', $value_for_param2);
etc...
```

Also, why are you adding `%` to your bound values. In an SQL context, `%` is generally used for `LIKE` wildcard matching, and normally isn't added to inserted text the way you're doing.

As well, using `try/catch` would only be useful if your DB library (PDO?) is set to throw exceptions. Which would mean that your `$errorInfo` stuff would never execute, as the `execute()` or `prepare()` calls would have thrown an exception at that point. Either use exceptions, or use "return false for failure". Not both.

Comment: Thanks Marc, that was the nudge I needed to understand what was happening with the ":param1" as it works into the SQL. Does this SQL look right? "INSERT INTO :questionNumber (:answerNumber) VALUES (:answerText)" I'm getting an SQL format error, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''q1' ('a1') VALUES ('Answer 2')' at line 1"

Comment: no. placeholders are only for VALUES. You can't use them to specify tables or fields. e.g. `where foo = :bar` is ok. but `where :foo = :bar` is wrong, because it'll be treated as comparing two values. `where 'foo' = 'bar'`, not `where insertedfield=somevalue`. e.g. anything that's an sql keyword is offlimits for a placeholder.

Comment: I see. SO then going to "INSERT INTO $questionNumber (:answerNumber) VALUES (:answerText)" is where I'm at but with the error still. "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''a1') VALUES ('Answer 2')' at line 1"

Comment: if your values are showing up in the error text, then you're still doing something wrong. that kind of syntax error should've been caught at the `prepare()` stage.

Answer (score 0):

To connect the database:

```
$db = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'database');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
```

You can also use bind_param() function:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ? (?) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('iis', $questionNumber, $answerNumber, $answerText);
$stmt->execute();
```

In that way you do you dont set any param's in your query... You directly insert the variables to your query string.

```
 INSERT INTO *table* VALUES (:param1, :param2, :param3, param4,...);
```

for the query string, and then

```
$stmt->bindValue(':param1', $value_for_param1);
$stmt->bindValue(':param2', $value_for_param2); 
$stmt->bindValue(':param3', $value_for_param3); 
$stmt->bindValue(':param4', $value_for_param4);
```